# when I run local server and try to open a csv file by url(ajax), I got 404

Tags: javascript, ajax, localserver

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "uhslc.soest.hawaii.edu/data/csv/rqds/atlantic/daily/d740a.csv",
    //url: "d741a.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {processData(data);}
 });
```

I want to make it work on my client side but when I run localhost, the address is localhost:0000/uhslc.soest.hawaii.edu/data/csv/rqds/atlantic/daily/d740a.csv and when I run locally, the address is as my/local/address/uhslc.soest.hawaii.edu/data/csv/rqds/atlantic/daily/d740a.csv so it does not work. Is there any way I can download a file from that address whenever I run code?

Comment: Prepend the "url with `http://` so that it's fully qualified. E.g. `http://uhslc.soest.hawaii.edu/data/csv/rqds/atlantic/daily/d740a.csv`

Comment: Thank you mardubbles! Just adding http:// solve this prob!!